# Could not find class databinding.FragmentBinding

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, kotlin

I'm trying to use databinding in my fragment but I get the following error on runtime:

```
Could not find class 'com.example.databinding.FragmentUpSellBinding', referenced from method com.example.UpSellFragment.onCreateView
```

Which results into:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: nl.anwb.fietsen.debug, PID: 5563                                                                     
java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBindingUtil.inflate(…r,                                                                                     
false) must not be null`
```

my build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-alpha4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Main buid.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    ext{
        supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: First, I'd like to confirm you've included the Kotlin standard library dependency: `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"`. Second, try cleaning and remaking your project from the "Build" menu in Android studio.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question with a little bit more information

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle in you don't need

```
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

Remove and try

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-alpha4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And update your Kotlin to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sanne, I have the exact same build.gradle files as you, except for a newer gradle -alpha9 and don't get the runtime error from onCreateView when using DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,...).

In my case dataBinding { enabled = true } is required.

However I did get a build error (Unresolved reference: databinding) when using FragmentXBinding.inflate(inflater) until I specified FragmentXBinding.inflate(inflater as LayoutInflater).

Comment: My code with the binding is in a module and not in my main project do you have the same setup?

Comment: No, mine's in main app.  Sorry, I glossed over the plugin statement.